# Redirect whole website or pages to /wp-admin in wordpress

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to redirect every page of the website to /wp-admin either login or not.i tried every solution which I got from google.

Comment: Can you explain the use case a bit further? You can blanket redirect anything except starts with wp-admin to wp-admin with a htaccess redirect.

Comment: You can also configure the site to require login always, or use a stub theme with just a single index.php that redirects to the admin site. What's this for, though? Are you just using WordPress as a CMS-backed REST API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to StackExchange. As mentioned on comments by @aravona and @Rup it will be harder to give you a good answer without more context.

In any case, I think you have a couple basic approaches to achieve what you want: using WordPress [`template_redirect` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) or .htaccess files rules (or NGINX configuration rules in case you are using NGINX instead of Apache).

The most performant would be `.htaccess` file rules, and NGINX configuration file rules, but it would be more prone to redirect errors or breaking things on the admin side if you are not experienced with these. Therefore, I suggest avoid it and stick to the `template_redirect` hook.

## Using the Template Redirect Hook

You can use the following code in a theme, a plugin or [Must-Use Plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/) (i.e. MU Plugin). I suggest using either a plugin or, even better, a MU Plugin, which is [called before normal plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request).

```
/**
 * Redirect All WordPress frontend requests to the /wp-admin/
 *
 * Redirect All WordPress frontend requests to /wp-admin/, except for WP Rest API endpoints.
 * Adapted from a idea by BraadMaring at https://github.com/BraadMartin/only-rest-api .
 *
 * @uses wp_safe_redirect
 * @uses admin_url
 */

function wpse355549_redirect() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( admin_url(), 301 );
        exit;
    }
} 

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse355549_redirect', 10 );
```

Basically, this will check if the request isto a /wp-admin/ URL. It f not, it will safely redirect to the /wp-admin/

Caveat: some customizer related pages are not detected by `is_admin`. API endpoints will also be accessible.

Comment: Thanks, Celso Bessa.